# What is the different between Android signed certification vs a platform certification ? 

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

What is the different between Android signed certification vs a platform certification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every application installed on an Android device needs to be **signed with a certificate** or the emulator/device will refuse to run it.

During testing/debugging the Android tools will automatically create a test certificate and sign the app with it when deploying to the emulator or a physical device. For releases e.g. to the Android market the developer has to create a certificate and use it to sign the app; using the same certificate to sign updates to an app allows Android devices to recognize it being from the same developer.

Applications signed with a **platform certificate** can obtain additional privileges, e.g. [rebooting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT), shutting down or even [bricking](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BRICK) a phone.

On unrooted (retail) Android phones, there is usually no way to sign your own application with a platform certificate as these are kept private by OEMs (Samsung, HTC, etc.) or Google. On rooted phones, you can install a custom ROM with a platform certificate of your own and also sign apps with that -- with all the consequences.